# Printing decimal to ascii character, my command does not output as intended

Tags: bash, shell, character-encoding, ascii

I wanted to output a string of all the ascii characters with the following command

```
for i in `seq 32 127`; do printf "%c" $i; done
```

The output of the above command is:

```
33333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777..............
```

It's the first (from the left) digit of each number.

Looking through this site I came across the answer to my problem [How to print all printable ASCII chars in CLI?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15139/how-to-print-all-printable-ascii-chars-in-cli), however I still don't understand why my original snippet does not output the ascii characters as intended.

Comment: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html) dictates this, here's a [`comp.unix.shell` thread](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2007-07/threads.html#00050) on why it's the right thing `;)`

Comment: @sr_ Thanks for pointing out the thread. It had the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't directly print the ascii codes by using the `printf "%c" $i` like in C.

You have to first *convert the decimal value of i into its octal value* and then you have to print it using using `printf` and putting `\` in front of their respective octal values.

To print `A`, you have to convert the decimal 65 into octal, i.e. 101, and then you have to print that octal value as:

```
printf "\101\n"
```

This will print `A`.

So you have to modify it to :

```
for i in `seq 32 127`; do printf \\$(printf "%o" $i);done;
```

But by using `awk` you can directly print like in C language

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=32;i<=127;i++)printf "%c",i}';echo
```

Comment: In `bash` and `zsh` this can be done without the loop and without the external command: `printf $(printf '\%o' {32..127})`.

Comment: @manatwork: ya exactly..thanks a lot for pointing it out..

Comment: @pradeepchhetri : Thank you for the detailed response and it seemed to cover most of the required details (hence I choose your answer). However I guess it missed out an important piece of information which can be found in the following message at http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2007-07/msg00262.html. It states that "The argument operands shall be treated as strings if the corresponding conversion specifier is b, c, or s..."

Comment: Isn't `(char)(127)` backspace or something like that. Whatever it is, it appears as one of the hex-boxes or whatever they are called. If you want only the "printable" (i.e. readable), just go to 126. Also, nice thought with the octal. That's clever; I was thinking in terms of hexadecimal (like `printf '\x%x; {32..126}` ... or 127, I guess, since all of you did it, too), but it doesn't work. Octal saves the day! :) Finally, @Ifthikhan, I'm not sure what you mean. `awk` often uses C-style commands and nowhere else is `%c` used. Using octal numbers is different than using one-byte characters.

Answer (score 3):

`%c`    Interprets the associated argument as char: only the first character of a given argument is printed

You seem to already have a way to print them, but here is one variant.

```
for i in `seq 32 127`; do printf "\x$(printf "%x" $i) $i"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `printf`, but only once; you can replace one use of `printf` by the simpler and more efficient `echo` plus Bash escape sequences:

With hexagesimals:

```
for i in `seq 32 127`; do
  echo -ne \\x$(printf %02x $i)
done
```

With octals:

```
for i in `seq 32 127`; do
  echo -ne \\0$(printf %03o $i)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you prefer keeping the `printf` format string as constant as possible, change:

```bsh
for i in `seq 32 127`; do printf "\\$(printf %o "$i")"; done
for i in `seq 32 127`; do printf "\x$(printf %x "$i")"; done  # not POSIX
```

to

```bsh
for i in `seq 32 127`; do printf %b "\0$(printf %o "$i")"; done
for i in `seq 32 127`; do printf %b "\x$(printf %x "$i")"; done  # not POSIX
```

(Incidentally, the [POSIX standard for `printf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) doesn't include `\x` among the escape sequences allowed in the format string.)

I prefer keeping the `printf` format string as constant as possible because of separation of concerns. The format string's concern is formatting; the arguments are for data that varies. Also a problem could occur if an expansion in the format string includes things that could be interpreted as format specifiers, as discussed [here](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/CCPPOBJ/Non-constant+format+string) in the context of C programming. Also discussed here: ShellCheck linting rule [SC2059 Don't use variables in the printf format string](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2059).